# UITextView is not editable but textViewDidEndEditing still being called

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

I have an app where a number of `UITextViews` and they are all set `enabled=NO` in `viewDidLoad`. However when you double click on any one of them in the simulator `textViewDidEndEditing` is called.

Can anyone explain why this might be happening?

Comment: Try with `editable = NO`

Comment: I tried that - thanks - but that did not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try
    [textView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];